# Is it possile to convert a nested list of tuples to an numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a nested list of tuples:

```
tuple_list = [[(0, 0.022190866145025672),
  (1, 0.03713307553569147),
  (2, 0.03329292095418187),
  (3, 0.013397487788645558),
  (4, 0.012968754425823006),
  (5, 0.02303938132767878),
  (6, 0.5055000245070915),
  (7, 0.02148198409145118)],
 [(0, 0.027141399289287292),
  (1, 0.034094330130799384),
  (2, 0.18793352530921031),
  (3, 0.01545954116652308),
  (4, 0.03658418672184262),
  (5, 0.1929824217980975),
  (6, 0.021051003033754387),
  (7, 0.03489076576637312)]]
```

As you can the the nested lists are of same lenght.

Is it possible to convert it to a numpy array?

I already tried to convert it to a numpy array like this:

```
y = numpy.array(tuple_list)
```

But I get this result:

```
array([list([(0, 0.022190866145025672), (1, 0.03713307553569147), (2, 0.03329292095418187), (3, 0.013397487788645558), (4, 0.012968754425823006), (5, 0.02303938132767878), (6, 0.5055000245070915), (7, 0.02148198409145118), (8, 0.028544808844256947), (9, 0.023656766961056515), (10, 0.058975765442311284), (11, 0.052628865356187236), (12, 0.019632103194206267), (13, 0.017715501743987942), (14, 0.013181486857172771), (15, 0.03693920037515881), (16, 0.059811388273952625), (17, 0.019909618176120435)]),
       list([(0, 0.027141399289287292), (1, 0.034094330130799384), (2, 0.18793352530921031), (3, 0.01545954116652308), (4, 0.03658418672184262), (5, 0.1929824217980975), (6, 0.021051003033754387), (7, 0.03489076576637312), (8, 0.027263833771125616), (9, 0.022274146808526914), (10, 0.1321132498202665), (11, 0.034287197030052854), (12, 0.021483869200653788), (13, 0.033468696091416075), (14, 0.014070713898823948), (15, 0.029487668742227795), (16, 0.025213173521698867), (17, 0.11020027789932013)])
```

My desired result would be like this:

```
array([[(0, 0.022190866145025672),
  (1, 0.03713307553569147),
  (2, 0.03329292095418187),
  (3, 0.013397487788645558),
  (4, 0.012968754425823006),
  (5, 0.02303938132767878),
  (6, 0.5055000245070915),
  (7, 0.02148198409145118)],
  [(0, 0.027141399289287292),
  (1, 0.034094330130799384),
  (2, 0.18793352530921031),
  (3, 0.01545954116652308),
  (4, 0.03658418672184262),
  (5, 0.1929824217980975),
  (6, 0.021051003033754387),
  (7, 0.03489076576637312)]])
```

As further information, I need the nested list in an array to compute the Jesen-Shannon Divergence between two distributions.

Comment: `np.array(tuple_list)`?

Comment: Hi @jdehesa I tried this and got a weird result. I added it to the OP.

Comment: You're not supposed to get this result, I tried it on my own and got what you expected using np.array(tuple_list)

Comment: What is the desired result?

Comment: What do you mean @ThomasSchillaci?

Comment: Hi @YamiOmar88, I added my desired result to the OP.

Comment: check my answer again I update that for you

Comment: Are you sure that your divergence function expects a ndarray of list of tuples? That's a pretty weird way of storing the numbers.

Comment: np.array(tuple_list) works for me with numpy 1.17.5

Comment: Yes, of course.  Maybe the way the conversion, as implemented by Numpy's `array`, is performed is different from your expectations but I'd suggest, rather than reconsidering Numpy's ways, to reconsider your expectations.  The array you get, that incidentally is different from your reported result, is perfectly fine to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I have done this in traditional for loop way:

Yes you can convert tuple into list by using `list()`
 method

```
  tuple_lists =[[(0, 0.022190866145025672),
  (1, 0.03713307553569147),
  (2, 0.03329292095418187),
  (3, 0.013397487788645558),
  (4, 0.012968754425823006),
  (5, 0.02303938132767878),
  (6, 0.5055000245070915),
  (7, 0.02148198409145118)],
 [(0, 0.027141399289287292),
  (1, 0.034094330130799384),
  (2, 0.18793352530921031),
  (3, 0.01545954116652308),
  (4, 0.03658418672184262),
  (5, 0.1929824217980975),
  (6, 0.021051003033754387),
  (7, 0.03489076576637312)]]

temp=[]
tuple_into_list=[]
for tuple_list in tuple_lists:  # looping through list of elements and those elements contains tuples
    for tuple_item in tuple_list:
        temp.append(list(tuple_item))  #converting tuple into list and adding it into a list object
    tuple_into_list.append(temp) #finally adding a temp object which is a collection of converted tuple into list 
    temp=[] #make it empty so in another iteration the converted tuple  into list of elements will be there

tuple_into_list
```

**Output**

```
[[[0, 0.022190866145025672],
  [1, 0.03713307553569147],
  [2, 0.03329292095418187],
  [3, 0.013397487788645558],
  [4, 0.012968754425823006],
  [5, 0.02303938132767878],
  [6, 0.5055000245070915],
  [7, 0.02148198409145118]],
 [[0, 0.027141399289287292],
  [1, 0.034094330130799384],
  [2, 0.18793352530921031],
  [3, 0.01545954116652308],
  [4, 0.03658418672184262],
  [5, 0.1929824217980975],
  [6, 0.021051003033754387],
  [7, 0.03489076576637312]]]
```